# Calling the nested function issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, nested, call

I'm trying to call the nested function from the library of cryptos js, but it doesn't work and throws an error.
The below code is just the library code from crypts lib
in that I'm tried to call 117th line

Its my call code `var n= CryptoJS.Base.Create()`
Code link:- https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yvnec8zh

Error throws up

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
```

I can't find the solution to this matter

Comment: The error says: `Cannot find module 'crypto-js'`. You may want to try `crypto` module instead. It would be better if you tried that in any IDE, not an online compiler.

Comment: @jkalandarov i just shared for ref. in my actually tried in IDE which also installed the crypto js module. check my error above

Comment: In order to be able to use `crypto-js` it should be installed and you should be able to find it in `node_modules` directory. `crypto` is a native module in nodejs, you can use and import it without installing it.  I am not sure how to require modules from npm registry on online compiler.

Comment: @jkalandarov i know the import and i did all. what I problem was I don't know how to call the 117th line create function on the code. that is